# Unconditional arithmetic circuit lower bounds for permanent/determinant

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

In this http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.12.1090&rep=rep1&type=pdf an unconditional lower bound (provided constants used are bounded by absolute value smaller than $1$) of $\Omega(n^2\log n)$ for size of arithmetic circuits computing $n\times n$ Matrix Multiplication is given.

What is the best unconditional lower bound for size of arithmetic circuits computing $n\times n$ Matrix Determinant and Permanent along similar lines?

Comment: The lower bound is only for circuits with small constants.

Comment: There are some surveys on arithmetic circuits – have you looked at them?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I looked at this one http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~shpilka/publications/SY10.pdf it gave specific cases like multilinear, monotone and certain depth but could not find what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kalorkoti](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0012780) gave an $\Omega(n^3)$ lower bound on arithmetic formulas for the determinant and permanent. As far as I know, nothing is known for unrestricted circuits.